# Regular Expression String Mangling Efficiency in Python - Explanation for Slowness?

Tags: python, regex

I'm hoping someone can help explain why Python's re module seems to be so slow at chopping up a very large string for me.

I have string ("content") that is very nearly 600k bytes in size.  I'm trying to hack off just the beginning part of it, a variable number of lines, delimited by the text ">>>FOOBAR<<<".

The literal completion time is provided for comparison purposes - the script that this snippet is in takes a bit to run naturally.

The first and worst method:

```
import re
content = "Massive string that is 600k and contains >>>FOOBAR<<< about 200 lines in"
content = re.sub(".*>>>FOOBAR<<<", ">>>FOOBAR<<<", content, flags=re.S)
```

Has a completion time of:

```
real    6m7.213s
```

While a wordy method:

```
content = "Massive string that is 600k and contains >>>FOOBAR<<< about 200 lines in"
newstir = ""
flag = False
for l in content.split('\n'):
    if re.search(">>>FOOBAR<<<", l):
        flag = True
    #End if we encountered our flag line
    if flag:
        newstir += l
#End loop through content
content = newstir
```

Has an expected completion time of:

```
real    1m5.898s
```

And using a string's .split method:

```
content = "Massive string that is 600k and contains >>>FOOBAR<<< about 200 lines in"
content = content.split(">>>FOOBAR<<<")[1]
```

Also has an expected completion time of:

```
real    1m6.427s
```

What's going on here?  Why is my re.sub call so ungodly slow for the same string?

Comment: You don't include a reproducible test case, so I'll have to ask you to run the tests: try the non-greedy `.*?`: `re.sub(".*?>>>FOOBAR<<<", ">>>FOOBAR<<<", content, flags=re.S)`, and try specifying a count: `re.sub(".*>>>FOOBAR<<<", ">>>FOOBAR<<<", content, 1, flags=re.S)`. Do either of these (or both in combination) make it go faster?

Comment: How many times would `>` appear on its own before the full  `>>>FOOBAR<<<` token?

Comment: The keyword here is backtracking.  The dot-asterisk grabs all the text, backtracks, checks if there is `>`, if nit goes on.... It is overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no good way to do it with a pattern starting either with `.*` or `.*?` in particular with large data, since the first will cause a lot of backtracking and the second must test for each taken character if the following subpattern fails (until it succeeds). Using a non-greedy quantifier isn't faster than using a greedy quantifier.

I suspect that your ~600k content data are in a file at the beginning. Instead of loading the whole file and storing its content to a variable, work line by line. In this way you will preserve memory and avoid to split and to create a list of lines. Second thing, if you are looking for a literal string, don't use a regex method, use a simple string method like `find` that is faster:

```
with open('yourfile') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        result += line
        if line.find('>>>FOOBAR<<<') > -1:
            break
```

If `>>>FOOBAR<<<` isn't a simple literal string but a regex pattern, in this case compile the pattern before:

```
pat = re.compile(r'>>>[A-Z]+<<<')

with open('yourfile') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        result += line
        if pat.search(line):
            break
```

Comment: While the data isn't in a file (it's collected from many files on the system), it's true that the method I have in my question is slower than the other two for the reasons Casimir listed.

For my solution, I ended up leaving the .* method in place as it only ended up really mattering on systems that had 500,000+ line log files.